# RegEx is replacing spaces by a slash

Tags: c#

I'm using the following code to do a case insensitive replace:

```
returned = Regex.Replace(source, Regex.Escape(oldValue), 
                                 Regex.Escape(newValue), 
                                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but `Regex.Escape` causes my spaces to be replaced by a \

```
source = "Description: <module>";
oldValue = "<module>";
newValue = "Module 1 - Upload Data File";
returned = "Description: Module\ 1\ -\ Upload\ Data\ File";
```

I know it works if I remove the Regex.Escape but I'll be honest I can't remember why I used `Regex.Escape` but there must have been a reason and I don't want to break whatever was working before.

Any idea how I can fix\handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your values?

Comment: I got my answer but I've updated the question with values so it might be easier to read for the next person! Sorry if it wasn't clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Regex.Escape Method:** Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes. This instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters.

You shouldn't escape the `newValue` variable as it would replace any white space with its escape code:

From: `' '` -> To: `'\ '`.

Try removing the `Regex.Escape` from `Regex.Escape(newValue)` and it should work.